# Grouping object columns in Python

Tags: python, anaconda, grouping, pandas-groupby, aggregates

I am doing some analysis by grouping specific site locations by countries.

Here is the code part:

```
results[["Site ID"]].groupby(["Country Code"]).sum()
```

However this does not work because the column Site ID is an alphanumeric value in the form of **DE123451**. It has a country code in front and it should be able to be grouped by the Country name column.

Site ID                                    object
Number of Customers                        float

If I try to group it with Number of Customers the above mentioned code works.
I also tried to convert the column into a string column but it did not help at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
results[["Site ID"]].groupby(["Country Code"]).sum()
```

In the first part, you only take the "Site ID" column so the "Country Code" column is dropped.

Try grouping by "Country Code" and then taking the "Site ID" column and summing it up(or counting instead if that is what you're looking for.

```
# For Summing
results.groupby("Country Code")["Site ID"].sum()
# For Counting
results.groupby("Country Code")["Site ID"].count()
```